# How to get an IOrderedQueryable<T> after calling Skip() and Take()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, iqueryable, .net-6.0

I have a paging class that includes an `ApplyFilter()` method, which filters rows for the current page. Since paging generally only makes sense in sorted results, this method accepts and returns an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` (instead of just a `IQueryable<T>`).

I use it like this:

```cs
var query = DbContext.Items
            .Where(i => i.Value > 0)
            .OrderBy(i => i.SortColumn);

query = pagination.ApplyFilter(query);
```

But there's a problem with my `ApplyFilter()` method.

```cs
public IOrderedQueryable<T> ApplyFilter<T>(IOrderedQueryable<T> query)
{
    return query.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
}
```

The `Skip()` and `Take()` methods both return an `IQueryable<T>`, so I get an error that the return value cannot be converted from `IQueryable<T>` to `IOrderedQueryable<T>`.

How can I use `Skip()` and `Take()` and still have an `IOrderedQueryable<T>`?

Comment: The query has no order to apply a `ThenBy` to.  It doesn't make sense for it to be an IOrderedQueryable.  The whole point of that interface existing is to ensure `ThenBy` is only usable in direct response to an `OrderBy` call.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, but it would be a nicety. You can see from my code that calls it that an overload the also returns `IOrderedQueryable<T>` would be convenient.

Comment: The downsides of attempting to claim a query is ordered when it's not seems to *significantly* outweigh the costs of simply calling `AsQueryable` on an ordered query that no longer needs to use a `ThenBy` (or simply using a new variable, as is usually the preferable option, variables aren't expensive to use).  Use the correct solution for the problem at hand.  Treating an ordered query as a general query is fine, treating a non-ordered query as if it's ordered is just causing trouble for yourself.

Comment: @Servy: Great points. Too bad `AsQueryable()` has to allocate additional objects. I don't think it's minimal overhead.

Comment: What objects you you think it's going to allocate?  It has *substantially* less overhead than any possible implementation you could ever conceivably come up with to turn a query into an ordered queryable (which could never possibly avoid any allocations in code that wouldn't throw at runtime).  `AsQueryable` does nothing other than change the compile time type of the object.

Comment: @Servy: Well, I'm not exactly clear on all the details but, looking at the source code for `AsQueryable()`, I do see a call to `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Comment: It just does a type check and a cast.  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs,080010ec4b6beced If you're writing code so performance sensitive that the type check is going to be costly to you (which is going to be literally never since you're writing a database query that will be many, many orders of magnitude longer) you could write out the cast by hand rather than using `AsQueryable` to save the type check.  The JITter might even optimize it out, but I wouldn't consider it worth checking given how much of a non-issue it is.

Comment: @Servy: Yeah, you're right. It's already an `IQueryable` so the type cast is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something cheesy, like

```
public IOrderedQueryable<T> ApplyFilter<T>(IOrderedQueryable<T> query)
{
    return query.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).OrderBy(i=>1);
}
```

At least for SQL Server the codegen was smart enough to ignore the OrderBy.

Or change the return type to `IQueryable<T>`, and don't reuse the query variable:

```
var q = db.Set<User>().OrderBy(u => u.id);
var q2 = ApplyFilter(q);
```

Or change the argument and return type to `IQueryable<T>` and throw an ArgumentException if someone passes one that isn't an `IOrderedQueryable<T>`

```
public IQueryable<T> ApplyFilter<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
{
    if (query is IOrderedQueryable<T> oq )
    {
        return oq.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Query must be IOrderdQueryable<T>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that hack is rather unsightly. Too bad you can't simply convert an `IQueryable<T>` to an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` somehow. (Without appending another operation.)